# Error message in CGFloat

Tags: objective-c

I'm scoreboard app, where i't need to add a UItextfield and label on button click. I keep getting errors in these to methods. Any suggestions?

Error message:
"Assigning to 'UIView *' from incompatible type 'double'"

```
    self.yOffset = 60.0;
```

Error message:
"Assigning 'CGFloat' (aka 'float') from incompatible type 'UIView *'"

```
    frame.origin.y = self.yOffset;
```

Error message:
"Invalid operands to binary expression ('UIView *' and 'CGFloat' (aka 'float'))"

```
    self.yOffset += frame.size.height;
```

Here is the code:

```
-(void)addPlayerTapped:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Adding Player");
    self.yOffset = 60.0;

    UIViewController *llVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    llVC.view.alpha = 0.0;
    [self.playersArray addObject:llVC];
    [self.view addSubview:llVC.view];

    [self repositionFields];
}

-(void)repositionFields {

    // Reposition each view in the array
    for (DetailViewController *llVC in self.playersArray) {
        CGRect frame = llVC.view.frame;
        frame.origin.x = 15;
        frame.origin.y = self.yOffset;
        llVC.view.frame = frame;
        self.yOffset += frame.size.height;
    }

    // Add some animations to make it look nice
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        CGRect frame = self.addPlayerButton.frame;
        frame.origin.y = self.yOffset;
        self.addPlayerButton.frame = frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        DetailViewController *llVC = [self.playersArray lastObject];
        llVC.view.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}
```

Comment: How do you declare `yOffset`?

Comment: @property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat *yOffset;

Comment: That should be `CGFloat yOffset`, not `CGFloat *yOffset` — you don't want that to be a pointer.

Comment: Please post the actual code and error messages. The one you posted clearly tell that you declared it as `@property (assign, nonatomic) UIView *yOffset;`.

Comment: This is the error message i'm getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the error messages it looks like you declared `yOffset` as a `UIView *` instead of `CGFloat`, i.e. something like

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) UIView *yOffset;
```

whereas it should be

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat yOffset;
```